# Custom Taxonomy - Show primary first followed by rest in alphabetical order

Tags: customization, taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy and Yoast SEO installed. For a post, if I have set 3 terms from the custom taxonomy and one of them is primary, is there a way to show the primary custom taxonomy term first followed by the rest in alphabetical order?